# Removing children DOM elements in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a Javascript cart. I could add the products to my cart correctly but I am working on the `delete_item()` function.. When I click the × to delete an item only disappear the item name and the × of that item remain there. And if I change code position in the function, when I click in × to delete the item, the × disappear but the item name remains there.. I could not do it, I mean that both should disappear..
And with the `refresh();` for the items name and `rel();` for the × of each product I refresh the cart.

```
function delete_item (nomP, idP, price, k) {
    idProduct.splice(k,1);
    nameProduct.splice(k,1);
    price.splice(k,1);

    $('#dlt').empty();
    document.getElementById("dlt").appendChild(rel());
    $('#nameProduct').empty();
    document.getElementById("nameProduct").appendChild(refresh());  
    return false;
};
```

EDIT: I MADE IT WORK

```
function pro () {
        rel();
        refresh();
      };
      function rel () {
          for (k = 0; k < idProducto.length; k++) {
          function dlt() {
              var element = document.createElement("p");    
              element.innerHTML = "<p class='close' type='button' onclick=\"return borrar('" + nombreProducto[k] + "', "+idProducto[k]+", "+precio[k]+", "+k+")\"><span>&times;</span></p>";
              return element;
          }
          document.getElementById("dlt").appendChild(dlt());
          }
      }
      function refresh () {
          for (j = 0; j < idProducto.length; j++) {
              productNames();
              document.getElementById("nombresProductos").appendChild(productNames());
          }
      }
```

So, the delete function..:

```
 function delete_item (nomP, idP, price, k) {
        idProduct.splice(k,1);
        nameProduct.splice(k,1);
        price.splice(k,1);

      $('#nombresProductos').empty();
      $('#dlt').empty();
      if (($('#nombresProductos').is(':empty')) && ($('#dlt').is(':empty'))) {
        pro();
      };
    return false;
    };
```

Comment: Post some html too to replicate the problem..,

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Javascript

```
for (j = 0; j < productArray.length; j++) {
    function productNames() {
        var element = document.createElement("p");
        element.innerHTML = productArray[j];
        return element;
    }
    document.getElementById("nameProduct").appendChild(productNames());
}
function refresh () {
    for (j = 0; j < productArray.length; j++) {
        productNames();
        document.getElementById("nameProduct").appendChild(productNames());
    }
}

for (k = 0; k < idProduct.length; k++) {    
    function dlt() {
        var element = document.createElement("p");    
        element.innerHTML = "<p class='close' type='button' onclick=\"return delete_item('" + productArray[k] + "', "+idProduct[k]+", "+precio[k]+", "+k+")\"><span>&times;</span></p>";
        return element;
    }
    document.getElementById("dlt").appendChild(dlt());
}
function rel () {
    for (k = 0; k < idProduct.length; k++) {
    function dlt() {
        var element = document.createElement("p");    
        element.innerHTML = "<p class='close' type='button' onclick=\"return delete_item('" + productArray[k] + "', "+idProduct[k]+", "+precio[k]+", "+k+")\"><span>&times;</span></p>";
        return element;
    }
    document.getElementById("dlt").appendChild(dlt());
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nameProduct" class="col-xs-6 col-md-7">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 text-right">
    <p>$105</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very poor code style! Where did you learn to place the javascript logic inside the `<div>`?

Comment: I've attempted to fix the formatting but I'm still not sure this is a usable answer.

Comment: @XO It is still the same issue.

Comment: @XO Thank you anyway.